# Very slow response of the Virtual Machines

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualenv, virtualization

We have recently purchased the new server having 16 GB of RAM. We have created 5 virtual machine. Out of these 5 virtual machines three are windows VM and the remaining two are Linux VM.

We have been contsantly facing the poor response of the virtual machines and the network / infra team is not able to tell us the root cause of the problem and providing the solution.

Can you please let me know what could be the possible cause of the slow down.

Additionally, we want to have the audits conducted to see if the infrastructure / network for our company has been setup correctly. Can you please let me know what are the typical audit parameters we evalluate for the best performance of Network and SYstems resources.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Memory (RAM) is being distributed among so many VMs, each VM has very less RAM available for its own use.